# Can we get a different icon?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Right now the icon for this SE site is a blue speech bubble that says XTZ (the one for the meta site is the same in black). Would it be possible to get a nicer icon there? Something along the line of the (ꜩ) logo?

Comment: Now that Tezos Stackexchange is out of beta its possible to change that afaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All beta sites have the boring logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322198) of the speech bubble with the initials inside. Sadly, sites don't get a special, awesome design until they are out of beta. So, until Tezos is out of beta, it's going to have to keep this default logo.

Comment: Incidentally, the favicon for most blockchain sites started with with their official currency code, which is where the XTZ was derived.

Comment: Now that Tezos Stackexchange is out of beta, how can it get its own logo?